# Lost on java scripting, Adobe dynamic stamp

Tags: javascript

I have created a dynamic stamp in adobe and added a date field and signature field, which both work completely fine when I stamp a set of shop drawings. However, there are 4 separate boxes that can be checked and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the check boxes to work. Any help with this is greatly appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDOg7.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom dialog with either a dropdown (with the check box entries) or 4 check boxes, then pass the values into the stamp fields.

Comment: Thank you! However I am new to all of this and don't even know where to start with it. Any help is greatly appreciated.